# Can i do soft coding in selenium webdriver using java?

Tags: java, android, selenium, xpath

So here's the problem i have to write driver.find() method for every element which cannot be iterated and of course on every page elements change.So my question is, is there any way so that i can soft code my test rather than hard coding it as it becomes very difficult to make changes.Is there any way so i can get the parameters or values or xpaths etc from a table say from LibreOffice.

Here is a part of my current implementation:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'Modules')]")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'Sales Module')]")).click(); 
driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("File")).click(); 
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'NEW')]")).click(); 
driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Enquiry")).click(); 
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'Domestic')]")).click(); 
if(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(.,'Sales Enquiry Form')]"))!=null){ 
    System.out.println("Success"); 
} 
else{ 
    System.out.println("Failed"); 
}
```

Comment: Could you add what you have implemented so far as well as an example to for what you want to implement?

Comment: driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'Modules')]")).click();
   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'Sales Module')]")).click();
   driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("File")).click();
   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'NEW')]")).click();
   driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Enquiry")).click();
   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'Domestic')]")).click();
   if(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(.,'Sales Enquiry Form')]"))!=null){
    System.out.println("Success");
   }
   else{
    System.out.println("Failed");
   }

Comment: continued.. driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'Modules')]")).click();
   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'Sales Module')]")).click();
   driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("File")).click();
   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'NEW')]")).click();
   driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Enquiry")).click();
   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'Domestic')]")).click();
   if(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(.,'Sales Enquiry Form')]"))!=null){
    System.out.println("Success");
   }
   else{
    System.out.println("Failed");
   }

Comment: so here is what i can show you rest i do not have the rights to expose so my question is that all the xpaths or IDS or names etc. Can they be entered in a table and i write a code that takes these parameters from that table i have created and also can the same be done for if else statements.

Answer (score 1):

Currently there are three approaches going on,

1. Read your locator from property files.
2. Page Object Model +  Page factory.
3. Hybridization of above two. With page factory it will be difficult as you need to create customPageFactory but it is possible.

Choose an approach as per your needs.(how frequently locators will be changed?, how much effort you are required to put in? Do you need a long term or a short term solution? etc)

Now leaving up to you to look for these three approaches on stackoverflow or online. as they are discussed many times.

Comment: Yes that seems like a good idea i am currently researching on the topics you mentioned thanks Kavan.